# Unknown data type error for parameters in select clause

Tags: java, jdbc, prepared-statement

I want to query my database (H2) using the following code:

```
PreparedStatement x = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO tree(ancestor, desc) (select ancestor,? from tree where desc = ? union all select ?,? )");
x.setInt(1,99219);
x.setInt(2,4);
x.setInt(3,99219);
x.setInt(4,99219);
```

but it doesn't work and I get the following error:

```
org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: Unknown data type: "?, ?"; SQL statement:insert into tree(ancestor, desc) (select ancestor,? from tree where desc = ? union all select ?,? ) [50004-192]
```

Executing the query in the console (without JDBC) works fine. What is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 0):

```
"INSERT INTO tree(ancestor, desc) (select ancestor,? from tree where desc = ? union all select ?,? )"
```

This SQL statement is incomplete. it is mising a `FROM` part after this:

```
union all select ?,?
```

Comment: but it works in raw database query. I learn this from [link]http://image.slidesharecdn.com/modelsforhierarchicaldata-100520123959-phpapp02/95/models-for-hierarchical-data-53-638.jpg?cb=1372768889

Answer (score 0):

The column returned by UNION select have to match by type the columns in the first select. You can do an explicit cast.